# Facebook's condensed multi friend selector layout and rendering

Tags: facebook, iframe, facebook-iframe

This is my first time working on a facebook app. I created an iframe app (i.e selected 'iframe' as the 'canvas type' when registering the app). I have this situation where there is a multi friend selector form in the sidebar of the app (which has a width of about 200px).
**Screenshot:** [image]

The relevant code for generating that form is as follows (except the *html* tag which is part of the app layout):

```
<html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

 // some layout markup here for the whole app....

<div id="sidebar">  // place a condensed friend selector here
<fb:serverFbml>
    <script type="text/fbml">
          <fb:fbml>
             <fb:request-form action="invite_url" content="
          Hey! a form!" invite="true" method="post" type="sample">
                <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Invite your friends to check out this site" condensed="true" exclude_ids="" max="20" showborder="true" style="width: 300px;" />
                <fb:request-form-submit label="Send" />
             </fb:request-form>
          </fb:fbml>
     </script>
</fb:serverFbml>
</div>
```

When i click on "Send invitations", i get a confirm dialog box but it appears within the iframe in which the multi-friend selector is placed (thus breaking the layout) and not on the parent iframe where the main app loads.
**Screenshot:** [image]

I tried the following code (where i remove the *fb:serverFbml* tag):

```
<fb:fbml>
 <fb:share-button></fb:share-button>
 <fb:request-form type="my_app" method="post" invite="true" content="Form content" action="/action">
  <fb:multi-friend-selector actiontext="Invite your friends to check out this site" condensed="true" exclude_ids="" max="20" showborder="true" style="width: 300px;"></fb:multi-friend-selector>
    <fb:request-form-submit label="Send" />

  </fb:request-form>
</fb:fbml>
```

Here the share button is displayed but the selector form is empty (nothing is rendered inside the *fb:multi-friend-selector* tag)

I am using the FB initialization code as described here: [link text](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript)

How can i fix this issue? Is there something missing in my fb api code?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem and found a solution here:
http://alexandershapovalov.com/facebook-multi-friend-selector-dialog-width-is-incorrect-73/

Try changing your **fb:serverFbml** tag to the following:

```
<fb:serverFbml width="200px">
```

Note that this doesn't work if you set the with in a style attribute and you may find that you need more than 200px to fit the dialog.